# I can't check or uncheck items in Security & Privacy > Accessibility on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, security, catalina, privacy

Since I installed macOS Catalina I can no longer check or uncheck some items that appear under **Security & Privacy > Accessibility**. First I click on padlock button on the lower left side of the screen to allow me to do the changes, but when I click on one of the items nothing happens.

One of this item that won't change is `org.chromium.chromoting.me2me.sh`.

Answer (score 4):

Just try to delete that specific item you want to check or uncheck and then add it back again.

Comment: How can I delete an item there?

Comment: Below the list of items there are "+" and "-" buttons, click on the item first and then click on the "-" button so that you can delete that item. Likewise, click "+" button and choose the item from the application folder to add it back again.